# Sphere distortion when attached to path

Tags: constraints, path, distort

I'm new to Blender. Now I'm working on a low-poly model of Earth orbiting Sun and I have a strange problem. I added Follow Path constraint to my Earth so it follows elliptic path around the star. But for some reason if I rotate Earth by Z axis (and follow path is added) there is a distortion (see image). How can I fix this? I need animation of following path and rotating by Z axis too. Thanks[image: earth distortion]

Comment: Add the image first.

Comment: What? It's in the post, no?

Comment: apply the scales of your object, also make sure the curve's vertices radius are at 1 (in the N panel)?

Comment: Thanks, I just found the answer. To make my path elliptical I scaled it by X axis and object on it's path has been automatically scaled too. I don't see any logic tho, but at least I can fix that.

Comment: if you want to avoid that, scale in Edit mode, if you scale in Object mode, the scale of the object itself will change and affect its children

Answer (score 1):

To make my path elliptical I scaled it by X axis and object on it's path has been automatically scaled too.